# How to block future submissions after submitted a certain times?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm trying to create a website where people can submit stuff. The user can see how many times there already is submitted in the current month and how many submissions can still be done. What I want is when the submit limit has been reached for this month, the website should block any future submissions for this month. How do I get it that it blocks ONLY this months future submissions? I still want people to be able to submit in other months.

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$currentDate = date("m");
$currentDate2 = date("F");
$maxSubmissions = '7';
$monthChecker[] = array();

$monthQuery = "SELECT * FROM submissions
           WHERE MONTH(dateRelease)= '$currentDate' ";

if($result = $db->query($monthQuery)) {

//Count amount of reservations of current month and show them
$teller = $result->num_rows;
if($teller == $maxSubmissions){
    //The limit has been reached
    $monthChecker['limit'] = "Het reserveringslimiet voor " . $currentDate . " is al bereikt.  ";
    if($teller > $maxSubmissions){
    // I think that i should write something here, but I have no idea what...
    }
} else{
    // the limit has not yet been reacherd
    $monthChecker['nolimit'] = "Er is in " . $currentDate2 . " al ".$teller." keer gereserveerd";
}


} else {

//if error
die("mysqli error: " . mysqli_error($db));
}
```

Comment: Do you have registered users or guests can submit ?

Comment: only registered users can submit

Comment: `WHERE MONTH(dateRelease)= '$currentDate' AND user='registered'";`

Comment: Then one solution would be a table where you store user_id, submission_id or something like that. That way you will always know what is submitted by which user.

Comment: I already have a table like that, i just want it to block future submissions on current month

Comment: @Fred-ii- what's the use of that? That query is just to show people how many submissions have been made in current month

Comment: Store a counter column in your database which is checked every time the user tries to submit data and when the month ends reset the counter

Comment: What present values are you getting from your current code? Plus, you may want to do `if($teller >= $maxSubmissions){` hard to say because I for one don't know what your code does; not without knowing what your values are.

Answer (score 0):

If you are attempting to limit each individual user to only 7 submissions per month then you need to reduce the set you return by that userId. For instance if your submissions table also includes a userId you could add in the following and clause:

```
$monthQuery = "SELECT * FROM submissions
       WHERE MONTH(dateRelease)= '$currentDate' 
           AND userId = $userId";
```

Though you may be required to use a join if this data is relational.

You may have a secondary issue here with the Year as well, as the above will target MONTH specifically. If there is no clean up mechanism on the submissions table you may end up with prior years submissions affecting current years counts.